# Files in pdf format in one place

Tags: windows-7, document-management

I want to ask you if it is possible that every pdf document that I download goes always to a specific folder so that I can have them always in one place. Is there a way I can tell the Computer to always store my pdf documents downloaded to a specific folder? I am using windows 7.

Regards
Costas

Comment: Usually it is in the Downloads Folder

Answer (score 0):

Use IDM (Internet Download Manager) and set document to be download to a specific folder.